# Persisting non-serializable values in react native

Tags: react-native, background-process, sip, react-native-webrtc, sipjs

Is there any way to persist non-serialisable values in react native?

I am building a calling app using SIP js, everything works fine. Now i want to implement the call receiving functionality when the app is killed (The thing below is what I think can help me to reach my goal. I don't know whether I am going right or no, so any other ways are accepted too).

Now to achieve this, I want to persist the userAgent session so that I can use the same session in background. So when receiving a notification when the app is killed (notifications are already implemented), i can use the same userAgent session.

Comment: What is the data you want to persist?

Comment: @abe i want to persist the userAgent session. So the condition is like this, when i reopen the app, the useragent is registered again, i dont want that, i want to have the older userAgent to be used so that i can receive the calls in backgorund too.